# Javascript innerHTML into form text value

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript code that has an innerhtml function, like this

```
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("gps");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = position.coords.latitude + 
    "," + position.coords.longitude;
}
</script>
```

and I want to enter the output from the javascript code above to be entered into the input text form value

```
<input type="text" id="gps" name="gps" value="">
```

but I can't get the results I want, is there a code that I have to add or change?

Comment: try `x.value = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";` instead of innerHTML

Comment: could you please clearly write what do you want to do your functions and which result you want to get? because this is not clear to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call your function.

Assuming your `<script>` block is at the bottom of your page, after the `<input>` has been rendered this should work:

```
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("gps");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = position.coords.latitude + 
    "," + position.coords.longitude;
}

getLocation();
</script>
```